# Maps v2 Info Window doesn't display when marker is touched, but does after touching invisible Info Window

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm currently displaying a single marker. When touched the info window is NOT displayed. I've confirmed that the title is actually being set in the marker.

However, if I touch the area above the marker in which the info window would be, I do get the `OnInfoWindowClickListener` event. When this happens I open another activity, and when I return from this activity the info window is displayed (actually, I can see it being displayed a split second before the activity starts).

Any tips on how I can get the info window to display when the marker is touched?

This is my relevant code:

```
// .... more code up here


final GoogleMap map = mMapFragment.getMap();

if (map == null) {
    mReloadWhenReady = true;
    return;
}

map.clear();

final TileProviderMapsV2 prov = new TileProviderMapsV2(mMapFragment.getActivity());
map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(prov));


final LatLngBounds.Builder bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
final Map<Marker, MyNode> markerMap = J.newHashMap();
mNodes.clear();
mNodes.addAll(nodes);


L.p("Maps v2 nodes: %d. ", mNodes.size());



for (MyNode node : mNodes) {
    final LatLng latlng = new LatLng(node.getLat(), node.getLon());
    final MarkerOptions opts = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latlng)
            .title("Title is " + node.getName())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(com.mydomain.droid.R.drawable.pin_blue));

    final Marker m = map.addMarker(opts);
    markerMap.put(m, node);
    bounds.include(latlng);
}

map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        final MyNode node = markerMap.get(marker);
        L.p("Maps v2 Clicked Node: %s/%d. ", node.getName(),node.getId());
        ViewNode.Launchr.setNodeId(node.getId()).launch(mMapFragment.getActivity());
    }
});
```

If I add `m.showInfoWindow();` inside the for loop the marker *will* display the info window, however in the future there will be a lot more markers, so requirement is to only show the info window when the marker is touched.

For debugging purposes I added the following code, and I'm seeing the message in the logs along with the correct title, but I'm not getting the info window:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        L.p("marker clicked " + marker.getTitle());
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set a `OnCameraChangeListener`? If so, can you post your `onCameraChange` code?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are having this rendering issue but I'm gonna give you some tips that may or may not fix it.

First of all you should get rid of the if block that checks if map is ready and also get rid of the mReloadWhenReady flag. The correct way to initialize a google map is using the `getMapAsync` from your Map fragment.

So implement the `GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener` and the `OnMapReadyCallback` in your class And do the following to initialize, setup and use a map.

declare a member map variable

```
private GoogleMap map = null;
```

Then somewhere in your class initialize that map

```
mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

then write some code inside those overriden methods

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        //here you can be sure the map is initialized correctly
        this.map = googleMap;
         //here we set the info window listener
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this); 
        setupMap() //your custom method for doing whatever you want to do with the map see below
    }

    //Do your stuff on onInfoWindowClick as usual
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        final MyNode node = markerMap.get(marker);
        L.p("Maps v2 Clicked Node: %s/%d. ", node.getName(),node.getId());
        ViewNode.Launchr.setNodeId(node.getId()).launch(mMapFragment.getActivity());
    }



private void setupMap()
 {

    map.clear();

    final TileProviderMapsV2 prov = new TileProviderMapsV2(mMapFragment.getActivity());
    map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(prov));


    final LatLngBounds.Builder bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    final Map<Marker, MyNode> markerMap = J.newHashMap();
    mNodes.clear();
    mNodes.addAll(nodes);


    L.p("Maps v2 nodes: %d. ", mNodes.size());



    for (MyNode node : mNodes) {
        final LatLng latlng = new LatLng(node.getLat(), node.getLon());
        final MarkerOptions opts = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latlng)
                .title("Title is " + node.getName())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(com.mydomain.droid.R.drawable.pin_blue));

        final Marker m = map.addMarker(opts);
        markerMap.put(m, node);
        bounds.include(latlng);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        marker = m;
        L.p("marker clicked " + marker.getTitle());
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `The method showInfoWindow() is undefined for the type MarkerOptions`

Comment: Hi Hammad, I've updated the original question with your suggestion to add `showInfoWindow()` in the for loop. This will show the info window, however I need it to be displayed only when the marker is touched (which should be the default behaviour of the marker).

Comment: The variable `m` is not defined in that scope. Also, in the future there will be many markers, so the `marker` variable should be used in the `onMarkerClick` method.